# any way to keep side cell height intact after middle cell height increases of a table row

Tags: html, css

I dont know how to put this but i need an alternate way to do this.I have a row like below :

```
<tr>
 <td class="leftside">small image here</td>
 <td class="middle"> label to display BIO of a person</td>
 <td class="rightside">small image here</td>
</tr>
```

Here, when the bio is very large, the height of row increases and the left and right side cells also increase ..which is obvious.But it looks very bad because there is a big gap between the small image (either on left or right side) and the next item below it (which is in next row).Is there a way where i can display the side contents properly(without any gaps) even when the row height increases due to large BIO?

Comment: Upload your images and give me a jsfiddle, so I can play with the code....

Comment: I have no idea what effect you're after. Unless I severely misunderstand what you want, your description is physically impossible.